# JQuery Validation is not working, I disabled the html form validation manually

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I have the below page, I was trying to use JQuery validation to validate a registration form, but it didn't work, I appreciate your input.

```
                   <div id="left">
    <div id="Welcome">
      <h1 class="pageHeading">Eurotech Course Registeration</h1>
      <div class="bg"></div>
      <div id="form_block">

      <form name="frmFindProgram" id="frmFindProgram" method="post" novalidate="novalidate" action="do-register.php?lang=">

        <div class="field_box">
          <div class="field_lbl">Course Title</div>
          <div class="field_element">

              <input type="text" required id="coursetitle" name="coursetitle" value="" />
              <input type="hidden" id="coursecategory" name="coursecategory" value="" />

          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="field_box">
          <div class="field_lbl">Course Date</div>
          <div class="field_element">

              <input type="text" required id="coursedate" name="coursedate" value="" />

          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="field_box">
          <div class="field_lbl">Course Place</div>

             <input type="radio" name="coursecity" id="coursecity"  value="" />&nbsp;
             <input type="radio" name="coursecity" id="coursecity"  value="" />              
        </div>

        <div class="field_box">
          <div class="field_lbl">First Name</div>
          <div class="field_element">

              <input type="text" required id="firstname" name="firstname" value=""/>

          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="field_box">
          <div class="field_lbl">Last Name</div>
          <div class="field_element">

              <input type="text" id="lastname" name="lastname" value=""/>

          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="field_box">
          <div class="field_lbl">Position</div>
          <div class="field_element">

              <input type="text" id="position" name="position" value=""/>

          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="field_box">
          <div class="field_lbl">Department</div>
          <div class="field_element">

              <input type="text" id="department" name="department" value=""/>

          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="field_box">
          <div class="field_lbl">Company</div>
          <div class="field_element">

              <input type="text" id="company" name="company" value=""/>

          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="field_box">
          <div class="field_lbl">Mobile</div>
          <div class="field_element">

              <input type="text" required id="mobile" name="mobile" value=""/>

          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="field_box">
          <div class="field_lbl">Email</div>
          <div class="field_element">

              <input type="email" required id="email" name="email" value=""/>

          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="field_box">
          <div class="field_lbl">P.O Box</div>
          <div class="field_element">

              <input type="text" id="pobox" name="pobox" value=""/>

          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="field_box">
          <div class="field_lbl">Country</div>
          <div class="field_element">

              <select id="country" name="country" />
                                    <option value="Choose a country">Choose a country</option>

                <option value="
            United States">
            United States</option>
                <option value="
            Uruguay">
            Uruguay</option>
                <option value="
            US Minor Outlying Islands">
            US Minor Outlying Islands</option>
                <option value="
            USSR (former)">
            USSR (former)</option>
                <option value="
            Uzbekistan">
            Uzbekistan</option>
                <option value="
            Vanuatu">
            Vanuatu</option>
                <option value="
            Vatican City State (Holy Sea)">
            Vatican City State (Holy Sea)</option>
                <option value="
            Venezuela">
            Venezuela</option>
                <option value="
            Viet Nam">
            Viet Nam</option>
                <option value="
            Virgin Islands (British)">
            Virgin Islands (British)</option>
                <option value="
            Virgin Islands (U.S.)">
            Virgin Islands (U.S.)</option>
                <option value="
            Wallis and Futuna Islands">
            Wallis and Futuna Islands</option>
                <option value="
            Western Sahara">
            Western Sahara</option>
                <option value="
            Yemen">
            Yemen</option>
                <option value="
            Yugoslavia">
            Yugoslavia</option>
                <option value="
            Zaire">
            Zaire</option>
                <option value="
            Zambia">
            Zambia</option>
                <option value="
            Zimbabwe">
            Zimbabwe</option>                  
              </select>

          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="field_box">
          <div class="field_lbl">&nbsp;</div>
          <div class="field_element">
              <input type="submit" id="submitFormBtn" name="submit" value=""  />
              <input type="reset" id="resetFormBtn" name="reset" value=""  />
          </div>
        </div>


      </form>

<script type="text/javascript">

       $("#frmFindProgram").validate();

</script>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your page is broken because the code is nothing like what you've posted in your OP.

On your page, you have `input` elements outside of the relevant `form` container and [you should fix the broken HTML.](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http://eurotechintl.com.lin.arvixe.com/register.php&charset=%28detect%20automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0)

The code in your OP is working as expected:  http://jsfiddle.net/XZaA6/